# Get specific fields with MongoDb query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a schema like this

```
{
    _id:ObjectId(),
    ...,
    translations:[{
        value: "English",
        code:"en"
    },{
        value: "German",
        code:"de"
    }]
}
```

All object have a translation with code 'en' and 'de', How can I get all objects(value,id) with code 'en'? A The result should look like similar to this:

```
[{
    _id:ObjectId(),
    value:"English"
},....
...]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [**aggregation pipeline**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

- [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the `translations` array
- Use [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) to select the documents with `code 'en'`
- Use [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) to include or reset fields in your result.

```js
    db.collection.aggregate(
        [
            { "$unwind": "$translations"}, 
            { "$match": { "translations.code": "en" }}, 
            { "$project": { "value": "$translations.value", "_id": 1 }}
       ]
    )
```